# When to use assets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, assets

What is the best way to use assets in Flutter , for example if i have a file for app configuration , should I store the file by getting the app directory using the path_provider plugin -without using assets- and store it ?, or should I add the file to my program folder -add the file to my assets- ?

the same question if I have a small Sqlite database.

and which of these methods is faster , and which is more secure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets are files that you add to your app during development. You can load them with `rootBundle.load()` or `rootBundle.loadString()` but you cannot modify or delete them.

In the app's directory you can store any files that your app downloads or generates from the internet while running. These files can then be opened, deleted, modified, etc. To access your app directory you need the package `path_provider`, which tells you the path to your app folder.

A sqlite database is normally stored in the app directory. An example package would be here [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite).

For speed and security I can't make a difference. An app directory is designed so that only the app can access it. Assets are a part of the app, the application file can theoretically be unpacked by anyone. Therefore I would at least not store secret things in the assets.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if by app configuration you mean the user's settings you can use Sqlite, SharedPreferences or Hive (Hive shows a benchmark that says that it is faster than SharedPreferences).

I believe that assets folder is used to store some common files for the app, like images, icons, fonts, etc. And I think that isn't recommended to store files with some kind of config file, mainly with critical info about the app configuration.